# Ranorex ran with Jenkins - can't find excel file

Tags: jenkins, ranorex

I have specified Jenkins job that tries to run Ranorex tests by running some .bat file on my PC. When I start this .bat file locally, it does all the required actions. But when it is runned with Jenkins, there is a log:

> 2015-12-10 15:57:23,51
>
> [2015/12/10 15:57:25.535][Debug ][Logger]: Console logger starting.
>
> [2015/12/10 15:57:26.016][Info ][Test]: Test Suite
>   'bulk_printing_invoice' started.
>
> [2015/12/10 15:57:26.534][Info ][Test]: Test Case 'TestCase' started.
>
> [2015/12/10 15:57:26.537][Failure][Test]: Test Case 'TestCase'
>   completed with status 'Failed'.
>
> [2015/12/10 15:57:26.539][Failure][Test]: Test Suite
>   'bulk_printing_invoice' completed with status 'Failed'.
>
> [2015/12/10 15:57:26.797][Debug ][Logger]: Console logger stopping.
>
> 2015-12-10 15:57:26,87

As far as I know, such situation occurs when Ranorex test suite cannot find data connector (my excel file). But as I said before it appers on my PC and is usable when I run those tests by double clicking bat file.

> Failed to get rows from data source: Failed to load Excel data.
>   Program Microsoft Excel can't access file „C:\Ranorex\RanorexStudio
>   Projects\UAT\MONITORING\1_1_2_bulk_printing_invoice\bulk_printing_invoice\bin\Debug\test_data_monitoring.xlsx”.

Can anyone tell me what to do?

Comment: Can you verify that the file "C:\Ranorex\RanorexStudio Projects\UAT\MONITORING\1_1_2_bulk_printing_invoice\bulk_printing_invoice\bin\Debug\test_data_monitoring.xlsx" exists? Usually, this is because the data file which is described by the connector in the test suite does not exist.

Comment: Yes, it does exist. As I mentioned in the question, it is the same file that script uses when I run it manually from my PC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue.
The problem was Jenkins running as Windows Service. After turning it off and running manually from command prompt with command

java -jar jenkins.war

problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

For debugging reasons I would copy the .bat script and inject it with the Jenkins job itself (Execute Windows batch command).

The issue probably is in how Jenkins handles it's work directory and other references for other file locations.

Most probably you will have to navigate out of the working directory and to a base bath with Jenkins batch command. Also you will be able to distinguish very well from Jenkins logs if the issue is in the paths.